# How react native interacts between native and JavaScript environments?

Tags: react-native

I am curious about the architecture of react-native and how it interacts between JS and native environments, specifically the life cycle of a component being converted from JS to a native component. I have explored this on official facebook links but except [this](https://code.facebook.com/posts/1014532261909640/react-native-bringing-modern-web-techniques-to-mobile/) I couldn't get anything useful. Any help will be great